# How does cmake find a package?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, makefile

I am trying to understand how cmake finds packages, using the `FindXXX.cmake` file. As an example, the library OpenNI has the file `FindOpenNI.cmake` defined here: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindOpenNI.cmake

Now, at the bottom of that file, there is the following:

```
if(OPENNI_FOUND)
  # Add the include directories
  set(OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS ${OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR})
  message(STATUS "OpenNI found (include: ${OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}, lib: ${OPENNI_LIBRARY})")
endif(OPENNI_FOUND)
```

What I do not understand is where the variable `OPENNI_FOUND` is defined, because this is the first point in the file that it is mentioned.

I would have thought that this file itself is used to find OpenNI, by searching the directories as dictated in the file's contents. However, it seems that `OPENNI_FOUND` must have been declared before. Therefore, it is confusing to me: `FindOpenNI.cmake` is being used to find OpenNI, but during that process, it has been given the variable `OPENNI_FOUND`, which itself tells cmake whether OpenNI has been found.

So how is cmake actually finding OpenNI? Using this file? Or some other way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CMake uses file you mentioned to find OpenNI. The `OPENNI_FOUND` variable is set by `find_package_handle_standard_args()` function. It is where the all magic is done, see the [documentation for it](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html).

Comment: Ah, ok. So if `FindOpenNI.cmake` file has both `find_path()` and `find_library()`, and both of these are found, then it will set `OPENNI_FOUND` to true? And if *either* of these are not found, then it will set `OPENNI_FOUND` to false?